# NullPointerException in onResume when modifying Buttons, why?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-2.1-eclair

I'm getting a NullPointerException raised from a number of my users, and I'm unable to spot what the issue is, it is thrown on this line :

`((Button)findViewById(R.id.speakEnglishButton)).setText("");`

I'm unable to see what is wrong, the button exists with that Id, it compiles fine, works fine on my emulator and 2 devices, however I'm getting about 100 or so errors being posted in my developer console for users on this version.

Looking closer at the onResume :

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean isButtonLabelsEnabled = sp.getBoolean("isButtonLabelsEnabled", false);
    if (!isButtonLabelsEnabled)
    {
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.speakEnglishButton)).setText("");
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.speakFrenchButton)).setText("");
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.speakSpanishButton)).setText("");
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.speakGermanButton)).setText("");
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.speakItalianButton)).setText("");
    }
    else
    {
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.speakEnglishButton)).setText(getString(R.string.btnLblEnglish));
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.speakFrenchButton)).setText(getString(R.string.btnLblFrench));
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.speakSpanishButton)).setText(getString(R.string.btnLblSpanish));
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.speakGermanButton)).setText(getString(R.string.btnLblGerman));
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.speakItalianButton)).setText(getString(R.string.btnLblItalian));
    }
}
```

Essentially, all I'm doing is checking for a saved preference boolean, and depending on its value I'm either setting labels on buttons, or setting them to blanks.

Can anyone please advise?

Thanks

Comment: Do all layouts have this button?

Comment: @PeterKnego there is only one layout, in res/layout/languageselection.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do all of those ((Button)findViewById(R.id.speakEnglishButton)).setText(""); ....
in onCreate()

Add

```
private Button mSpeakEngButton;
.....
```

As class variables, initialize them in onCreate()

```
public void onCreate() {

   ....
   mSpeakEngButton = ((Button)findViewById(R.id.speakEnglishButton));
}
```

Later in code you can modify their values as mSpeakEngButton.setWhatever()

Comment: But y are u getting this issue .. ??

Comment: @MohitSharma I never tried it that way. I prefer to have references to controls I'm working with instead of using look-ups when I need to use any of them.

Comment: but why this happened to him when onResume comes after onCreate callback?

Comment: I noticed this issue still happens on earlier versions of Android. It should not return null in onResume, since onResume comes after onCreate. Keeping a reference from onCreate is good practice though, findViewById does a linear lookup of views which uses a bit of time everytime a lookup is done.

Answer (score 7):

I think the point is that when the user resumes the activity the layout is not set and thus a `findViewById()` has no 'anchor' to look for and thus returning null.

You may just move the call to `setContentView()` from `onCreate` to `onResume` (given that you are not referencing views in `onCreate`. For normal usage this makes no difference as in the Android lifecycle, `onResume`is directly called after `onCreate` and before the user can interact with the activity.

Actually there is a bug in some applications where you visit an activity, then start a different one, perhaps leave the app for a different one, return and then return (via back button) to the first activity. Here all of a sudden you see a black screen. This is because the system "swapped" out the first activity and on returning only `onResume` is called, but not `onCreate`, so there is no chance to load the layout again there.

Comment: How would one resolve this? Setting the content view in onResume such as `setContentView(R.layout.languageselection);` ?

Comment: This is not expected in the Activity life cycle. Is it addressed by some Android issue ticket?

Comment: To be honest, I don't recall details, as this answer was 4 years ago. I recall though that I indeed ran into this at the time being and was debugging it. I have no idea if there is a ticket. Or if that got fixed meanwhile in newer Android versions.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely that's caused when

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.speakEnglishButton));
```

returns null.
This happens if such a resource cannot be found.
Spontaneously one reason comes to my mind: You do not have default resources in your layout.
That means: You **must** have at least one "default" layout, which applies for each language/orientation/... which should be placed in the folder "layout". Simply "layout".

Comment: The layout XML file where these buttons reside, is in res/layout/mylayout.xml, therefore it would be the default right?

Comment: @Michael:couldn't get u can please explain more

Comment: @MohitSharma The blind guess I was making is, that you should place one `layout.xml` in your `layout` folder. You might have `layout-de`, `layout-land`, but not one that is simply named `layout` - without any postfixes.

Answer (score -1):

If you keep setContentView() at onResume() instead of onCreate(), it will give inflate exception, I have tried this.